# Adding staints to paintwall (two image textures) - UV map problem

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to create simple box shaped column with two textures.
One is concrete, second vertical stains. I want to add this stain texture to the top of the column, but I encountered some really stupid problem. I can remeber one of my first blender projects was a model of TV. I use procedural (i meanjust grey BDSF haha) material for plastic colors and an image texture of the logo, but now I'm using TWO image textures. And I have a problem.

When I'm trying to mix these with MixShader node my stains are way too big. When I'm trying to scale up UV map with stain texture as a background, both stains and concrete texture getting bigger... Please help.

Comment: please show as many images as possible to make it more understandable, perhaps what you need is to create a second UV map for the second Image Texture and use an Input > UV Map node that you plug into this Image Texture node?

Comment: Yeah I just find tutorial for that I didint know that I can create second UV fo the same material, but stil. When I create that new UV thats the time when I can add that new image texture (with new UV map selected)? Then I can just select desired faces and click unwrap or smartunwrap and its done?

Comment: you can unwrap just one or several faces then plug the UV map node into the Image Texture, plug the Image Texture into a Diffuse then Mix Shader to mix it with the other image

Comment: by uv map node You mean this nodw which I can generate with ctrl+t using node wrangler addon? Sry I'm a blender noob.

Comment: In the Shader Editor (Node Editor in 2.7), press A > Input > UV Map, and in this node choose the new UV map you've created for the second image

Comment: My knowledge is limited here, but I believe you may need to go into the Shader Editor and create a new texture coordinate node and link it specifically to the stain texture, and make your changes to it within that node only, so as to prevent the other texture from scaling similarly. This is what immediately occurred to me as a possible course to take after reading your post, so if this isn't the answer, it may hopefully still put you on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let say you want to make this object, but the sign is a PNG image apart (make sure it has a transparent background):

[image]

Load your background picture, create your first UV map, put your UV on the background.

[image]

Load your sign image, create a second UV map, put the face(s) you want on the sign, reduce the other ones so that they don't overlay the sign (I thought I could create a one face map but it seems like not, perhaps someone will tell):

[image]

In the *Shader Editor*, use this node chain. Use the *Input > UV Map* nodes to tell what UV map Blender is supposed to use for each image (you don't need to use the first *UV Map* node as the first UV map will be chosen by default). For the stain's Image Texture, choose *Clip* instead of *Repeat* to make sure that the other faces are not overlaying the sign (or move them over a transparent zone). Don't forget to plug the alpha output into the *Factor* of the *Mix Shader*.

[image]

Comment: Yes what I missed is that UV Map node. I created it on the right column, but didin't inside shadder.